# C segmentation fault on linux with strncmp

Tags: c, linux, string, segmentation-fault, c-strings

This works ('Y' must be single quotes):

```
if (toupper(user_input(2)) == 'Y') printf("you said y");
```

This gives segmentation fault:

```
if (!strncmp((char *)toupper(user_input(2)), "Y", 1)) printf("you said y");
```

strncmp must be going off the deep end but not sure why since I'm passing a casted toupper() as (char *). Without the casting, same error.

FYI user_input() is (N.B. vars are global):

```
char* user_input(int size) { //size is the number of characters to capture. Remember to account for \n or \0
    if (fgets(buf, size, stdin) != NULL) { //buf is char buf[1000];
        if ((p = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) //Check if carriage return in string
            *p = '\0'; //Replace carriage return with NULL
        p = buf; //Set pointer back to input for others to access
        return *p;
   } else {
       p = buf;
       p[0] = "\0";
       return "\0"; //Return NULL if input fails
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're using C like java, C strings need manual memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.hmmmm... so not just `char buf[1000]; char *p;`? Why does the "if" version work?

Comment: Sidenote: I'm doing socket programming and using user inputs when programming to test protocol etc...

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give any error messages or warnings? Most of that shouldn't compile at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `toupper` is another character, not a pointer to a string. So you are trying access memory address 131 which is why you are getting a segfault. Since you are only interested in the one character, you can replace your offending line with:

```
if (toupper(user_input(2)) == 'Y') {
   printf("You said yes\n");
}
```

Notice that in the comparison `Y` is in single quotes which denotes you are dealing with a character value (as opposed to double quotes which denote a string value).

Comment: Ok thank you. Can't a char be considered a non terminated char array of 1 element at position [0] though?

Comment: Sure, technically it can be. If you wanted to write the above code this way you could go with. `x=toupper(...); strncmp(&x, "Y", 1);` but you couldn't do something involving `&toupper(...)`, that isn't valid C.

Comment: @J-a-n-u-s No. You're confusing an array (one or more storage locations that can contain values) with the contents of an array (one or more values contained in a storage location). When you say "char", you could mean a storage location (like `char a;`) or you could mean a value (like `'a'`). These are two different things.

Comment: @J-a-n-u-s, to put it another way, you are confusing *converting* (i.e. casting) the value of an object to a pointer with *taking the address of* that object.  They are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. I'll keep it simple and go with the if. All the best.